# can't access root user

Tags: root, debian, permissions

I came home from work and restarted my server pc just for a bit of refreshment and it turned on me and did the opposite.

I'm running OPEN MEDIA VAULT, it's been very good to me, until now, I used to be able to access it just by typing in the IP of the computer or computer name (omv) and it would give me a nice interface, it doesn't work now it just says:

> 500 Internal server error

I also used to be able to login via `ssh` using Putty as the **root** user but now it just says:

> connection refused

before I even get a chance to type in any login details. I can still log in as other users but I need root permissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you log in to ssh probably user root cant log (security reason), so , the procedure is log as other user and type "sudo su root".
Hope it helps.
sMl

Comment: When I try this it asks for the password, then once I enter it, it says 'setgid: Operation not permitted'

Comment: I just tried restarting yet again and I did notice that it gave me a warning "unprotected private key file!" Permissions 0777 for 'etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

Comment: Try with: sudo chmod 600 /var/run/sshd
chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
chmod 4755 /bin/su /usr/bin/sudo And try to log in with root.
sMl

Comment: It just says "changing permissions of 'bla' : operation not permitted.

Comment: Is /etc/passwd readable?